# Adding a date range picker with jQuery and updating content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following HTML which adds my table headings when you click on the `Add Column` button. Then when you click `Add Row` it creates the rows.

I need to add a date picker and create the button so that the user can pick a date range, then that date range needs to go into the respective travel dates row.

The user needs to click `Add Column`, then needs to click `Add Date Range`  and then it should put a date in the cell. The Add Date Range needs to have its own column showing in each row. Then when the user picks a range it should show up something like: `Fri, 20 Sep - Mon, 7 Oct 2013`

**HTML:**

```
<button id="addcolumn">Add Column</button>
<button id="addrow">Add Row</button>
<button id="adddaterange">Add Date Range</button>

    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

    <thead id="theads">
        <tr>
            <th class="th">Travel Dates</th>
            <th class="th">Duration</th>
            <th class="th">Trip Cost</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbody">

    </tbody>

    </table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $cell = $('<td>', {
        'class': 'td',
        'align': 'center',
        'contenteditable': '',
        'text': 'Content'
    });

    var $header = $('<th>', {
        'class': 'th',
        'contenteditable': '',
        'text': 'Heading'
    });

    $('#addcolumn').click(function() {
        $header.clone().appendTo('thead tr');
        $cell.clone().appendTo('tbody tr');
    });

    $('#addrow').click(function(){
        var $row = $('<tr>');

        $('th').each(function() {
            $cell.clone().appendTo($row);
        });

        $row.appendTo('tbody');
    });



});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/prBZS/35/

Comment: It must be a contenteditable td your can move to an input?

Comment: @Edward: No it should just change the value of the date cell/row. The date range button must still be there unless the users wants to change it. It should not be an input.

Comment: I am offering 50 rep points if you can help?

Comment: I'm working on it I'll let you know something ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up a fiddle, I illustrate how it works; I hope I undestand correctly what are you asking.

The project use a (I ca'nt set it hidden...) input field and attach to it a jQuery [`datepick`](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html); it's not used a standard jQuery UI datepicker because it isn't support the range selection.

When you add a column it will be added a class `canDatePicker` to every cell of the column, this class tells that can be "attached" a datepicker to the cell.
Using a contenteditable for every cell I managed the current focused cell by adding a class `focused`, so I know the current cell.
When you attach a datepicker to the cell it's added a class `hasDatePicker` to the cell for the future new clicks on the cell.

When you select the range from the datepicker the range is set on the text of the cell. If you click again on the cell the datepicker is opened with the cell range previously selected.

Let me know if you need more explaination of the code.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#datepicker').datepick({
        rangeSelect: true,
        onClose: function () {
            var dates = $('#datepicker').datepick('getDate');
            var value = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                value += (i == 0 ? '' : ' - ') + $.datepick.formatDate(dates[i]);
            }
            $('.focused').html(value);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('focus', '.hasDatePicker', function (e) {
        var dates = $(this).text().split(' - ');
        $("#datepicker").datepick('setDate', dates);
        $("#datepicker").datepick('show')
    });

    $(document).on('focus', 'td', function (e) {
        $("td").removeClass('focused');
        $(e.target).addClass('focused');
    });

    var $cell = $('<td>', {
        'class': 'td',
            'align': 'center',
            'contenteditable': '',
            'text': 'Content'
    });

    var $header = $('<th>', {
        'class': 'th',
            'contenteditable': '',
            'text': 'Heading'
    });

    $('#addcolumn').click(function () {
        $header.clone().appendTo('thead tr');
        $cell.clone().appendTo('tbody tr');
        $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(n+4)').addClass('canDatePicker');
    });

    $('#addrow').click(function () {
        var $row = $('<tr>');

        $('th').each(function () {
            $cell.clone().appendTo($row);
        });

        $row.appendTo('tbody');
        $('table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(n+4)').addClass('canDatePicker');
    });

    $('#adddaterange').click(function () {
        if ($(".focused").length == 0 || !($(".focused").hasClass("canDatePicker"))) return
        $(".focused").addClass("hasDatePicker");
        $("#datepicker").datepick('show')
    });


});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/WzkBS/

Start the demo, press Add row, Add column, focus the new cell and press Add date range, and try to use the demo.

Comment: thanks for this.. I cannot see how the date will go into the travel dates column? Demo isnt working as per your instructions..?

Comment: In the onClose function of the datepicker is set the html of the element that have the .focus class, is in the top part of the script

Comment: Ill award you with the rep points now. thanks for starting me off.

Comment: Thats quite cool, it works really well! thanks again! Please dont delete it from your jsfiddle account! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use start date and end date in
http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Or

can play around in 
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

for max and min of date range
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: I already know this. My problem is that i do not know how to create a new button which will know which row to apply the date.

Answer (score 0):

$( elementId ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/icons/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    minDate: (minDate)?minDate : "",
);